# How to create a log for errors and debugs in C#.Net

Tags: c#, logging

I have create a log file for maintain all the users who are logging into my application.

The code is `

```
string strLogText = txtLogin.Text;
StreamWriter log;

if (!File.Exists("logfile.txt"))
{
log = new StreamWriter("logfile.txt");
}
else
{
log = File.AppendText("logfile.txt");
}

log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
log.WriteLine(strLogText);
log.WriteLine();

log.Close();`
```

I want to  maintain all the errors and debug logs in my application. How should I start with those log files.

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of these free logging components:

- **[Log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html)**
- **[NLog](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/.NET_Logging_API)**

Comment: +1 yes and to start even logging in System.Diagnostic could be OK!

Answer (score 1):

NLog and Log4Net are great tools for logging exceptions etc.

If your application is web-based then I also recommend looking into Elmah which is a great logging tool for IIS web apps.